# Spring jdbc @Transactional annotation, procedure commits the transaction despite throwing appropriate exception

Tags: java, spring, plsql, transactions, spring-jdbc

```
Namastey,

We have a class and its methods as below-

    @Service
    @Component
    public class ReqServiceImpl implements ReqService {

    @Autowired
    private SubmitDAO submitDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = { CustomException.class },propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Map initiateSubmission(DetailsDTO vo) CustomException{

    //it has two method defined within the same class

        if(condition){
           Map resultMap = submitRequest1(map,vo.isTestMode());
        }else{
           Map result = (HashMap) submitRequest2(map,flag,vo.isTestMode());
        }


    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = { CustomException.class }, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void submitRequest1(Map map,boolean testMode) CustomException{

    submitDAO.simpleTableInsert1(map);
    submitDAO.simpleTableInsert2(map);
    submitDAO.procedureCall(map);

    if(!"success".equalIgnorecase(map.get("output"))){
    throw new CustomException("Service Layer | submitRequest1 | Proc Not successs");
    }

    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = { CustomException.class }, 
    propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void submitRequest2(Map map,boolean testMode) throws CustomException{
    submitDAO.simpleTableInsert1(map);
    submitDAO.simpleTableInsert2(map);
    submitDAO.procedureCall(map);
    }




    }
```

Below is our spring-servlet.xml file
In this, we have added our configuration for annotation, proxy and default advice to proxy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company,com.company.security.filter,org.springframework.jdbc" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven>

        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" name="defaultCharset"
                    value="UTF-8" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
        </mvc:message-converters>

    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator">
        <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
    </bean>


     <bean id="LogAspect" class="com.company.common.aop.LogAspect">
    </bean>
    <bean id="PerfAspect" class="com.company.common.aop.PerfAspect">
    </bean>
    <bean id="SessionAspect" class="com.company.common.aop.SessionAspect">
    </bean>


    <bean id="mailProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations" >
         <list>
            <value>classpath:db.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:dSource.properties</value>
        </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    </bean> 



    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" primary="true">
        <property name="jndiName" value="${DEVJNDI}"></property>  
    </bean>

     <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="DataSourceCo" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="${JNDINAMECOM}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager1"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSourceCo" />
    </bean>


     <bean id="myDataSourceI" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="${JNDINAMEI}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager2"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSourceI" />
    </bean> 

    <!-- Create a proxy to generate session-scope -->
     <bean id="userBean"
        class="com.company.common.session.UserDetailsSessionBean"
        scope="session">
        <aop:scoped-proxy />

    </bean> 

    <bean id="multipartResolver"

    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" 
    />`enter code here`


    </beans>
```

The method 'procedureCall' which is in another class has a procedure call inside.
The procedure does not have any commit inside.
After, the procedure return with any error, we throw an exception, but all in vain. The insert done by procedure still gets committed and transaction does not rollback.

The proc gives output "error" or "succcess", if there was any error. 
If we get any error "error", then we throw the customized exception.
It should rollback everything done inside proc, but that does not happen.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Kindly sugggest, if I missed any configuration. We are using spring 4.

Comment: Spring’s `@Transactional` does not rollback on checked exceptions

Comment: rollbackFor = { CustomException.class } is for that only, I think.

Comment: Just to make sure does your map contains output key in case the procedure call fails.

Comment: The proc gives output "error" or "succcess", if there was any error. If we get any error "error", then we throw the customized exception. It should rollback everything done inside proc, but that does not happen.